# How can I use type assertion on generic parameters

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

Suppose I have this code:

```
const items = {
  A: { x: 0 },
  B: { y: 0 },
  C: { z: 0 },
}
type Items = typeof items;

function foo<K extends keyof Items>(key: K, value: Items[K]) {}
```

This allows us to correctly enforce the type of parameters:

```
foo('A', { x: 0 }) // good
foo('A', { y: 0 }) // error
```

But how can I "assert" the type of generic parameter (or how to use some kind of type guard) when I'm inside `foo`?

```
function foo<K extends keyof Items>(key: K, value: Items[K]) {
  if (key === 'A') {
    // theoretically, if K is 'A', then Items[K] must be { x: 0 }
    const bar = value.x // But actually, it's error
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwjAvDA3gWAFAwwCCAXNjAB5kAMMAvgDT6EBCZWMAnjfUwTAGF2MAF49G%20OviicADohgBJJKgwwZ8kADN4KiAG58%20APTGtAVzDAoccDC0gQAHgDSMRBSRgAJmgDWiJzaSnoAfAAUAdwwLgwwAG4AhgA25ohkyigQANouALoAlNhSePgOIOEA5ESVcRxUMLR0RaYwAOaO3mWOVTV1XOItxu4ATiMgI0Z4FlY2duWu7p6IPv6BwZmoEVFksQkpaRl6uYXYzPA6kYEY6JjVlUW4-IStUAAWiBOINsApyZxxOA6NxwND3OLvFYhLInGDIczQGAAIwU9XE50IoEgsCRiRGaiSqUQADoKDBWixzLBEtZzH8AbpKmhEGMJucSnQgA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const items = {
  A: { x: 0 },
  B: { y: 0 },
  C: { z: 0 },
}
type Items = typeof items;

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Union = {
  [P in keyof Items]: [P, Items[P]]
}


function foo(...args: Values<Union>) {
  if (args[0] === 'A') {
    const [key,value] = args // [A, {x: number}]
  }
}
```

As you might have noticed, you have to destructure `const [key, value]...` after condition, not before. Otherwise, TS is unable to bind `key, value` with the union type.

Comment: Do you mean the very minor editorial change? :) I just swiped up when trying to find good questions to put a new [tag:generic-type-parameters] on

Comment: Yes ) Btw, good filter. I always used just [typescript]. I have never thought about using some advanced filters ) Thanks again)

Comment: NP, I just love creating and maintaining tags, however useless the current system makes them to be :)